# Accessing variables from two different sessions?

Tags: php, drupal, session, session-variables, whmcs

I have integrated WHMCS and Drupal. However, when you go to Drupal and you print_r the SESSION, you see completely different information than what you would do if you go to the WHMCS pages. So, my question is, how do I access the one's session, from the other one?

I need to access it, in order to see if the user is logged in or not.

Comment: Are you interested to use the Drupal session from WHMCS, or vice versa?

Comment: I want to access the WHMCS session from Drupal (so I can determine if the user is logged into WHMCS) (so that I can show or hide the login box on Drupal on other pages).

Answer (score 1):

The values you'll get depend on the `session.name` directive in `php.ini`. If you want them to be able to read each others', then set the same `session.name`.

Or rather, session data will be loaded based on the identifier in the cookie with the same name as `session.name`. This defaults to `PHPSESSID`, but you can change it yourself.

You can set this at runtime using `ini_set()` or `session_name()`.

Comment: Sure, but all `session_name()` does is changing that directive. See: http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_3/ext/session/session.c?view=markup#l1589

Comment: In the case of Drupal, the session name is set through code, not a `php.ini` directive.

Comment: @Daniel Egeberg: The session name used by Drupal is different from the session name reported in `php.ini`; `php.ini` doesn't report the name of the session currently set. I take that the problem the OP is having is to read the session created from Drupal using WHMCS, or vice versa.  I deleted my comment because I was not able to edit it, and it contained a typo; as it was the only comment, I thought I could do it. `:-)`

Comment: @kiamlaluno: It doesn't matter if it is set in `php.ini`. It's the name of `session.name` at the time where `session_start()` is executed that determines it. `session_name()` can also get the *current* session name. The bottom line is just that they need to be the same *somehow*.

Comment: I'm still stumped though. Even if I can set the session names, can you access other sessions?

Comment: @RD: Well, say that `session.name=PHPSESSID` (the default). If that's the case, then when you call `start_session()`,  PHP looks for a cookie called `PHPSESSID`. It uses the value of this cookie to lookup the session data in the storage. It's simply a matter of telling PHP how it's supposed to find the information.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal register its own session handling functions through [`session_set_save_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) during bootstrap ([`drupal_bootstrap()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_bootstrap/6)). It also sets it own session mame in [`conf_init()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/conf_init/6).

Because of the Drupal's handlers, restoring the WHMCS' session name before using standard PHP session will not work. PHP will use Drupal's hanlder to open, read, write, etc. session information. All you will get is the data for a wrong Drupal's session returned from [`sess_read()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/sess_read/6) when called by PHP.

One way to read WHMCS' session is to figure out how it is stored and to access it without using PHP's sessions functions.

Another way may be to *undo* what Drupal has done (changing session name and registering handlers) to restore *default* behaviors of PHP's session functions, read the WHMCS' session and restore Drupal's session name and handlers.